# Pytest6 and Python2? How to get them together?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I have a couple questions about QSYM and master-slave in AFL.

1. `export AFL_ROOT="/workdir/afl-2.52b"`
   `export INPUT="/workdir/example/input"`
   `export OUTPUT="/workdir/example/output"`
   `export AFL_CMDLINE="/workdir/example/test.bin @@"`
   `$AFL_ROOT/afl-fuzz -S afl-slave -i $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -- $AFL_CMDLINE`

When I put in `$AFL_ROOT/afl-fuzz -S afl-slave -i $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -- $AFL_CMDLINE`, an error "-S is undefined" appeared.

How do I fix this? According to the ReadMe file in AFL, I am certain that "-S" is a legit command.

2. QSYM uses an old version of Python (Python2), while to compile the Python files for QSYM I am asked to use the latest version of Pytest (Pytest6), which requires Python3.
   Even I tried to upgrade my pytest by using Python3 on my PC doesn't work, as long as it detects Python2, it doesn't let me upgrade pytest to version 6.
   An Error: `Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January,2020 please upgrade pytest to its latest version has appeared.`

What should I do?

To know more about QSYM, please goto this GitHub link: https://github.com/sslab-gatech/qsym

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest 5+ does not support python2

the last version which supported python 2.7 was 4.6.x

disclaimer: I am a pytest core dev

Comment: Hi, I understand that, and I would like to know if there's any way I can fix this issue? As I tried to use Python3 to upgrade Pytest, but it doesn't work.

Comment: your options are: (1) upgrade your application to python3 (python2 is end-of-lifed after all) or (2) downgrade pytest to 4.6.x